# One-sided "neutral zones" of plane curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an algebraic curve. We assume that for some $x_0 > 0$, the curve $C$ is given by $(x, f(x))$ where $f : [x_0, \infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is one-to-one and convex. We also assume that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = + \infty$.

For any $\vec x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, distance

$$\displaystyle d(C, \vec x) = \inf_{\vec y \in C} \lVert \vec x - \vec y \rVert$$

is positive if and only if $\vec x \not \in C$.

Define $C_{\geq x_0}$ to be the subset of $C$ consisting of $x$-coordinates at least $x_0$. For a set $C_{\geq x_0} \subset A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, we say that $A$ is a *neutral zone* for $C_{\geq x_0}$ if

$$\displaystyle A \cap \mathbb{Z}^2 = C_{\geq x_0} \cap \mathbb{Z}^2.$$

We then define the *positive half* of $A \supset C_{\geq x_0}$ to be

$$\displaystyle A^+ = \left\{(x,y) \in A : y \geq f(x)\right\}$$

and likewise, the negative half to be

$$\displaystyle A^- = \left\{(x,y) \in A : y \leq f(x) \right\}.$$

We consider, for $\delta > 0$, the region

$$\displaystyle A(\delta) = \left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x \geq x_0, d(C, (x,y)) \leq x^{-\delta} \right\}.$$

My question is: suppose that $A^+(\delta)$ is neutral, but $A^-(\delta)$ is not. Does it follow that $A^-(\delta)$ contains a rational curve $C^\prime$ with the property that as $x \rightarrow \infty$, $C_{\geq x_0}$ and $C^\prime$ converge?

The question is motivated by the following example. Let $x_0 = 2$ and $f(x) = 1/x$. Then the curve $C_{\geq 1}$ contains no integer points. Further, for any $\delta > 0$ the region $A^+(\delta)$ is neutral, but $A^-(\delta)$ is never neutral for $\delta \leq 1$, since the distance of $(x, 1/x)$ to $(x,0)$ is $1/x$.

Comment: even the first sentence only makes sense for odd degree